# Get multiple counts by 5 year increments

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table:

```
   index_melanoma_yr    Total_Melanoma  Total_Virus
    2000                700              12
    2001                746              7
    2002                724              12
    2003                815              15
    2004                893              16
    2005                1020             22
```

I would like to count by 5 year increments. So, 2000-2004, 2005-2009, etc. I can hard code this, but since there are so many years, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Here's how I got the initial counts:

```
    SELECT index_melanoma_yr,
           COUNT(DISTINCT PersonID) AS Total_Melanoma,
           SUM(   CASE
              WHEN index_virus_yr IS NOT NULL THEN
                  1
              ELSE
                  0
          END
              ) AS Total_Virus
    FROM Asare_ViralMelanoma_IndexDates
    GROUP BY index_melanoma_yr
    ORDER BY index_melanoma_yr
```

Comment: is it always `2010-2014`, will you have case like `2011-2015` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can perform some simple maths `year / 5 * 5` on the year column, and then `GROUP BY` that. Assuming that the `year` column is integer

```
SELECT  MIN(index_melanoma_yr) AS Year_Start,
        MAX(index_melanoma_yr) AS Year_End,
           COUNT(DISTINCT PersonID) AS Total_Melanoma,
           SUM(   CASE
              WHEN index_virus_yr IS NOT NULL THEN
                  1
              ELSE
                  0
          END
              ) AS Total_Virus
FROM Asare_ViralMelanoma_IndexDates
GROUP BY index_melanoma_yr / 5 * 5
ORDER BY Year_Start
```